# How to align TextButton's icon to right in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

With this sample code TextButton widget can be rendered with icon on the left side.

```
TextButton.icon(
  onPressed: onPressed,
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.arrowOpen,
    color: companySelectionColor,
  ),
  label: text,
),
```

However I want to use exact same widget but render the icon on the right side. Is there any way to render this icon on the right side?

Here is an example of the desired output:
[image]

Comment: how want you your output ? can you add image.

Comment: please check my answer and hope its help to you

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap the widget with `Directionality` widget. This widget can apply the given text direction to child widgets. With text button one can do following:

```
Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: TextButton.icon(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.arrowOpen,
       color: companySelectionColor,
    ),
    label: text,
  ),
);
```

Edit: You need to wrap your text with TextDirection.ltr as well. Which is a lot in a second thought. Just create your custom text button by implementing row/inkwell with text and icon

Answer (score 4):

I think as per documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/TextButton.icon.html) and as per my knowledge Icon is not right side position but you use using **Directionality()** widget its solved Just you use **ElevetedBtton.icon** instead of **TextButton.icon**  and its working correctly and you use **Directionality()** widget refer below code hope its help to you.

> Use ElevetedBtton.icon using **Directionality()** widget

```
     Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                label: Text(
                  "Pressed",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

> Use TextButton.icon

```
  TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              label: Text('Pressed'),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
```

> Use TextButton.icon using **Directionality()** widget

```
Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              label: Text(
                'Pressed',
                style: TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: .5,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your screen using ElevetedBtton.icon Widget  like -> [image]

Your screen using TextButton.icon Widget like -> [image]

Your screen using TextButton.icon Widget using Directionality() like ->[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering but isn't the answer that you've provided is same as mine? And also wrapping the textbutton with directionality causes the text to align on right if it has multiple lines. So you need to wrap your text widget with directionality as well.

All in all, I think it's not worth it to use TextButton.icon when you can implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextButton.icon(
      onPressed:null,
      icon: Text('2022-01-27'),
      label: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp),
    )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `IconButton` and add Text widget as a child alternatively.

```
IconButton(
   icon: Icon(Icons.arrowOpen),
   iconSize: 12,
   onPressed: () {},
),
```

Comment: Where can I put the text then?